Setup Azure App gateway point to private IP of internal load balancer of Azure container app env
I am setting up app gateway to route traffic to Azure container app but i dont want to use private dns zone. I want to use app gateway point to kubernes-internal load balcer auto craeted in MC_resource group to route traffic.
enter image description here
Can i setup this way?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

please provide more information by editing the question z@nguyendangsang


Setup Azure App gateway point to private IP of internal load balancer of Azure container app env without using private dns zone is not possible.

The direct answer I can say for this "NO". I understand that you are trying to setup a private Azure Container App behind an Application Gateway so that it is only accessible via the Application gateway and not accessible directly
Because without a private DNS zone or your own DNS server, the Application Gateway will not be able to resolve the internal FQDN of the Azure Container App to its IP address.
In general, this required for effective routing of traffic. For any internal container apps environment a priavte DNS zone or its own DNS server is mandatory which resolve the container apps domian name to stattic IP.
So its always mandatory to use a private DNS zone as per the recommondation.
Refer:
Azure Container Apps with internal load balancer - 403 error - Microsoft Q&A answered by GitaraniSharma-MSFT
